# Is it possible to get access to class-level attributes from a nose plugin?

Tags: python, testing, plugins, nose

Say I have the following test class:

```
# file tests.py
class MyTests(object):
    nose_use_this = True

    def test_something(self):
        assert 1
```

I can easily write a plugin that is run before that test:

```
class HelloWorld(Plugin):
    # snip
    def startTest(self, test):
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

The test is what I want it to be, but the type of `test` is `nose.case.Test`:

```
ipdb> str(test)
'tests.MyTests.test_something'
ipdb> type(test)
<class 'nose.case.Test'>
```

And I can't see anything that will allow me to get at the `nose_use_this` attribute that I defined in my TestCase-ish class.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT:*

I think probably the best way to do this is to get access to the context with a [`startContext`](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/interface.html#nose.plugins.base.IPluginInterface.startContext)/`stopContext` method pair, and to set attributes on the instance there:

```
class MyPlugin(Plugin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPlugin, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.using_this = None

    def startContext(self, context):
        if hasattr(context, 'nose_use_this'):
            self.using_this = context.nose_use_this

    def stopContext(self, context):
        self.using_this = None

    def startTest(self, test):
        if self.using_this is not None:
            do_something()
```

To be really robust you'll probably need to implement a stack of things since "startContext" is called for (at least) modules and classes, but if the only place where the attribute can be set is on the class then I think this simple thing should work. It seems to be working for me. (Nose 1.3.0 and plugin api version 0.10)

---

*original:*

Oh, it's the `_context()` function on the `test` instance:

```
ipdb> test._context()
<class 'tests.MyTests'>
```

And it does indeed have the expected class-level attributes. I'm still open to a better way of doing this, the `_` makes me think that nose doesn't want me treating this as part of the API.